# Convert barcode to number

Tags: barcode

What online tool can be used to convert barcode image into number? There are many tools available that generate barcodes (convert numbers to image), but I need convert image into number, saying what type of barcode is used and what number is encoded in the image.

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_7695949_convert-barcode-digits.html

Comment: What platform do you need? There are plenty of libraries ... java? .net? objective-c?  What kind of barcode? POSTNET? UPC? QR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Online web service: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx
- Java library: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/
- JavaScript for UPC: https://gist.github.com/tobeytailor/421369
- .net: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
- Ruby: http://gbarcode.rubyforge.org/

and on and on. Search `barcode decoder <platform>` for a list based on your favored language.