# Is there any other way to store barcode in database?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I generated barcode and i need to save it in mysql database. I know there are 2 ways of storing it. 1. Insert image with the data type blob and another is we can achieve it by setting the path of the png file... My question is. Is there any other way to store barcode details in mysql database other than the above mentioned?

Comment: Why not store it as a number?  Barcodes are basically images that represent numbers, so if you have a way to convert a barcode to a number and back again then it would make a lot more sense to store the barcode number (which will take up 4 bytes) than an image (that will take a lot more than 4 bytes).  I have worked a lot with barcodes in the past, and never once considered storing them as images.

Comment: How do i convert it? because i don't know how to do it i just want to learn on how we can achieve it. If you know any website or something else for learning this send me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595623/convert-barcode-to-number?rq=1

Comment: This one takes me to the online tool i don't want to use the online tool i need only the class. On clicking the save to database button it should convert the barcode image to number and save to database along with other details.

Comment: Okay, if you really just have images, and no easy way to convert them into codes/ numbers/ strings, then you are going to be stuck with the two options you describe in your question.  When I was working with barcodes I was supplied the UPC code by various retailers, and the problem was how to convert this back into a barcode again (trivial).  Your problem is actually much harder, as it's easier to go from a code to an image than an image to a code (which can result in issues with legibility, etc.).

Comment: Could you just help me out i just found a code for scanning and showing number on scanning barcode.

Comment: Okay, so the problem with this approach is that your scanner code will need to be able to save to the database, or your database code will need to be capable of calling the scanning code.  You will also need to cope with cases where the barcode can't be scanned, e.g. it comes up with no number.  Let me know what else you need, but don't stray too far off topic.  If this is no longer the original question then you may be as well starting a new question in stack overflow.

Comment: I create the barcode according to the employee id so the employee id and barcode that is generated are same so i can directly enter barcode in another textbox.

Comment: On scanning it with the barcode scanner how do i mark attendance? I created database with 30 days or i can store it as array of 30 values. And i mark 1 if present and mark 0 as absent. How do i put attendance present on scanning barcode and mark absent automatically when it is not scanned

Comment: Okay, this is starting to sound like a new question.  An employee/ student/ whatever (I will call it employee, but the same applies to all) attendance database will usually be dynamically built up, although there are many other ways to do this.  So you would have an employee table, with an employee id, then an attendance table with an employee id and a date for attendance.

Comment: When an employee signs in then you would scan their barcode, and create a new row with their employee id (I assume this is the barcode number) and the current date.  You would then assume that for dates with no record for a particular attendee that means that they didn't attend that date.  You might want a more complicated system, that records times as well, even when an employee enters/ leaves a building.

Comment: You might want to also Google "sql calendar tables".  These are used to provide a list of dates in a given month.  Then you would cross-reference this to your attendance table to see who was in on a particular day and who was absent.  Finding the number of days attendance in a month would be as simple as joining to the calendar table, adding a constraint, then counting the number of rows.

Comment: Yup as you said i'm just going from starting first i'm trying to add only date and attendance of the employee on the particular date and then improve the project with the date and time. On putting attendance the system should just search the database table that the employee is registered or not and then mark the attendance.